# Can I subscribe to a trello board's Activity list with something like Google Reader?

Tags: rss, trello

That way I could see all the activity and not just my notifications. I guess I'd be most interested in knowing when new cards are created... so perhaps just another notification option is all that's needed.

Comment: Here's the [feature request card](https://trello.com/card/board/rss-feeds/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e42de1112947f446501ddd1). Cast your vote! :-)

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think so. I've looked, and can't see it.

Also, RSS doesn't appear anywhere on [the Trello Development board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c), as a future request, and they already have their own near-instant notification system, with email messages sent out after 24 hours, if you didn't visit the Trello site.

So I doubt it would be a priority for them to implement RSS too.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like Trello is interested in implementing anything like RSS feeds, so I went ahead and made an [app that will create RSS feeds for your Trello boards](https://github.com/naiyt/trello-rss).

You're welcome to use the source from that to create your own feeds, or you can use [the webapp I created with it](http://trellorss.appspot.com/) to generate RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try [this](https://trellocalendar-francois2metz.dotcloud.com/) This web site could have you to build a rss link to subscribe to Google Calendar.